# My Proxy account for running SSIS job was working fine but now i am unable to edit or add new jobs using it

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using a proxy account for running the SSIS jobs. I have few other jobs using same proxy account and are referring to a config file in  shared folder location, which are working fine. But it isn’t allowing me to do that when I create any new job or edit an existing one.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please check how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: questions about permissions are better asked here:  dba.stackexchange.com